# Error VSSDK1001: Unable to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandTable.VSCTCompiler type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am attempting to update a Visual Studio extension to be compatible for installation in Visual Studio 2017.  I have followed the steps and notes in each of the following pages (and others I've searched):

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/faq-2017.md#can-i-build-a-vsix-v3-with-visual-studio-2015
- http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/01/10/its-time-to-change-the-vsix-manifest-of-your-extension-to-v3-for-visual-studio-2017-compatibility/

I originally encountered a separate issue noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676961/trouble-upgrading-visual-studio-extension-to-include-visual-studio-2017-compatib), which has been resolved. Now, the project (and extension) continue to build successfully locally, but it is failing on our TFS build server with the following error:

```
"d:\example\myproj\MyProj.csproj" (Rebuild target) (25:7) ->
  d:\example\myproj\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.BuildTasks.14.0.14.9.23\tools\VSSDK\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.Common.targets(67,5): error VSSDK1001: Unable to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandTable.VSCTCompiler type in 'd:\example\myproj\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.BuildTasks.14.0.14.9.23\tools\VSSDK\bin\VSCT.exe' Assembly. [d:\example\myproj\MyProj.csproj]
```

Has anyone else had any experience with this error to advise me as to why our build server is having this issue?

Additional note: I'm running Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) on both my local machine and on the build server in question.

---

**UPDATE (1/7/2019)**

The issue appears tied to the version of MSBuild.exe that is executed.

By default, our build server uses the version of MSBuild associated to the highest installed version of .NET (MSBuild version 4.7.3062.0, in our case). 
This version throws the error (VSSDK1001) from my original post.

If I manually perform the build using MSBuild version associated with VS 2015 (MSBuild version 14.0.27522.0), the error is eliminated and the build succeeds.  I have been, so far, unable to force TFS to use the desired MSBuild.exe version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this required updating the **ToolPath** property in the build process template used by our build definition, similar to what is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613114/how-does-team-foundation-build-choose-which-version-of-visual-studio-to-build-wi).

In our case, our build process template contains the "Run TfsBuild for Configuration Folder" step, and I needed to update the **ToolPath** property to a value of `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin"`

Answer (score 0):

> Error VSSDK1001: Unable to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandTable.VSCTCompiler type

You should add a nuget restore task before you build task in your TFS definition.

When you build in the local via Visual Studio, Visual Studio have two options to restore nuget packages automatically when we build the project:

[image]

But, when you build on the TFS server, there is no such options to restore those nuget packages automatically. So we need add a task nuget restore before we build the project/solution:

Add a task, search nuget and add it into the agent job, select restore in the Command:

[image]

Configure this nuget restore task correctly and set it before your build task.

Note: You can also add a `NuGet Tool Installer` task to specific version of NuGet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck, I'm afraid.  Tried adding the restore task, but it confirmed what I already suspected:

`NuGetRestore:
  Restoring NuGet packages
  "d:\example\myproj\packages\NuGet.CommandLine.4.7.1\tools\NuGet.exe" restore "d:\example\myproj\MyProj.sln"
  MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
  `

Comment: @kfelvoirny, thanks your reply. Have you add the `\packages` folder into the source control? If yes, please try to move it out of source control and check the source file on the TFS server, make sure you do not have that `\packages` folder.

Comment: We do have the NuGet packages folder in source control.  And we need it to remain there; we have deliberately have our builds set up to NOT auto-update NuGet packages so we're certain that what we're testing with locally is what is included in the TFS server builds.  Back to the source issue, can you explain what the error `Error VSSDK1001: Unable to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandTable.VSCTCompiler type` means and why our previous builds (that support VSIX installers for VS 2012, 2013, and 2015) didn't have the same issue until following the steps for VS 2017 compatibility?

Comment: @kfelvoirny, I am not familiar with the content of the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sdk.BuildTasks`, so I am not sure the reason for VSCT.exe can not find the Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandTable.VSCTCompiler type. I suspect that we add the package into the source control and submit it to the TFS, It will have a slight deviation because the path is not exactly the same as the local. Besides, AFAIK, if we not update the packages or set some attributes, VS/TFS/NuGet would not auto-update packages.